# Fullcalendar 2.3.1 agenda display overflow

Tags: html, css, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-2

I am trying to use Fullcalendar 2.3.1 and would like to ask for help in controlling the display of the timeslots.  Specifically I am using the agenda views for both days and weeks.  I have the minTime option set at '08:00:00' and the maxTime option set at '17:00:00' and all that works fine. I am trying to stop the area past 17:00 from showing (i.e., past the double line).

I have tried to find the css that controls where the agenda display stops but can't find it.  I have adjusted the .fc_slats and fc_time_grid values so that the area at the bottom is much smaller but I'm guessing that there is some parameter that one can use to stop that bottom space from being displayed at all.

Any help will be most appreciated, and thank you in anticipation.

Comment: If you're just starting off, why are you trying to use such an old version of fullCalendar? Version 6.x is the latest platform, and has lots of bug fixes, improvements etc compared to the much older editions. You should at least try using the newest version to see if there's any improvement in your issue, and so that you can take advantage of new features and enhancements more generally, plus continuing to be able to get updates and fixes, and having a simpler upgrade path to newer versions in future too. Unless you already have a large codebase using 2.3 and need to extend it, don't use it.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  I am working on an old website that uses Fullcalendar 2.3.1 so at the moment I'd prefer to continue using that version, but will give serious consideration to using V6 in the future.  Everything else works just fine and my issue is really more of an inconvenience rather than a major issue.  I am just trying to learn more about the various parameters that control the rendering of the calendar.  I do appreciate your interest so thank you again.

Comment: No problem. All the sizing options available through the API are listed at https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/sizing (v3 and v2 have the same API, so the docs for them are the same). I think you can also affect things by changing the height of the container element in which the calendar is situated (if any)

Comment: This is very helpful - many thanks - let's consider my question answered.  And thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the sizing options available through the API are listed at https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/sizing (v3 and v2 have the same API, so the docs for them are the same). I think you can also affect things by changing the height of the container element in which the calendar is situated (if any).

Comment: As mentioned above, this is very helpful - many thanks - let's consider my question answered.  And thanks again.